# Code works in console, but not when run by cron

Tags: python, cron

When I run this code works fine for console. It produces no error.

```
import sh
import uuid
import urllib

print 'Ip ....'
# Print only IP address from specific interface
LineaX = sh.grep(sh.ifconfig('eth0'), '-oP', '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}')
# Asignar Variables
IpX = LineaX.splitlines()[0]
PuertaX= LineaX.splitlines()[1]
MascaraX = LineaX.splitlines()[2]
MacX = ':'.join(['{:02x}'.format((uuid.getnode() >> i) & 0xff) for i in range(0,8*6,8)][::-1])
DataX = open('/etc/resolv.conf').read().split()
for item in DataX:
    if len( item.split(".") ) == 4:
        Dns1X = item
        Dns2X = '000.000.000.000'
    # Actualizar informacion
urllib.urlopen('http://www.miurl.com/file.php?mac='+ MacX + '&ip=' + IpX + '&mascara='+ MascaraX + '&puerta='+ PuertaX + '&dns1='+ Dns1X + '&dns2='+ Dns2X )
print 'Ip ... OK'
```

In cronjob produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/system/sensor_ip.py", line 7, in <module>
    LineaX = sh.grep(sh.ifconfig('eth0'), '-oP', '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 2301, in __getattr__
    return self.__env[name]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 2232, in __getitem__
    return Command._create(k, **self.baked_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 776, in _create
    raise CommandNotFound(program)
sh.CommandNotFound: ifconfig
```

What do I have that is wrong?

Comment: always show full error Traceback.

Comment: Why don't you read the error message and traceback ? They are here to give you as much clues as possible about what went wrong.  And then post the full traceback here if you _still_ need help.

Comment: what does the code do exactly, also the traceback should give you a line where the error happened, do you have multiple versions of python installed it might be running with the wrong one

Comment: In cronjob  this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/system/sensor_ip.py", line 7, in <module>
    LineaX = sh.grep(sh.ifconfig('eth0'), '-oP', '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 2301, in __getattr__
    return self.__env[name]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 2232, in __getitem__
    return Command._create(k, **self.baked_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 776, in _create
    raise CommandNotFound(program)
sh.CommandNotFound: ifconfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `sh` you need to import the commands you need, e.g.:

```
from sh import ifconfig
```

That's why you're seeing the error:

```
sh.CommandNotFound: ifconfig
```

If it's working fine on the shell but not in cron the issue is that you need to specify the absolute path to the binary because crons don't have a `path`.

Comment: Hi jbrown : I made the adjustment, but now I have this error:  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/system/sensor_ip.py", line 4, in <module>
    from sh import ifconfig
ImportError: cannot import name ifconfig`

Comment: if I have installed, I installed it this way:

`apt-get install python-pip
pip install sh`

Comment: Yeah should be that one then. Read the docs about giving the full path to the binary. It's probably the path issue in cron I mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem when reading sh.py directly!

Because `crontab` has its OWN PATH for shell or script running, `sh.py` executes `306     fpath, fname = os.path.split(program)`, it returns empty which means can't find `ifconfig` location in the PATH, so throw the NONE error.

```
 # /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py
 300 def which(program):
 301     def is_exe(fpath):
 302         return (os.path.exists(fpath) and
 303                 os.access(fpath, os.X_OK) and
 304                 os.path.isfile(os.path.realpath(fpath)))
 305
 306     fpath, fname = os.path.split(program)
 307     #lucifer
 308     #print 'fpath={0},fname={1}'.format(fpath,fname)
 309     if fpath:
 310         if is_exe(program):
 311             return program
 312     else:
 313         if "PATH" not in os.environ:
 314             return None
 315         for path in os.environ["PATH"].split(os.pathsep):
 316             exe_file = os.path.join(path, program)
 317             if is_exe(exe_file):
 318                 return exe_file
```

So you need to add the command(such as your `ifconfig` path in os.environ
I added it to my script.py for crontab

```
#Crontab PATH is not same compared with user.path
#This is for sh.commands
if '/sbin' not in os.environ['PATH']:
    os.environ['PATH'] += ':/sbin'
```

Bingo! Everything is ok!